# Does a react native app contain the WATCHMAN and Packager?

Tags: react-native

Does a react native app contain the WATCHMAN and Packager? What's more, does a react native app contain the source code of Javascript that I write?
To my knowledge,it only contain the jsbundle that Packager generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, compiled and shipped React Native app only contains native runtime (bridge, native modules etc) and minified transpiled bundle of your JavaScript code.

Watchman and packager are development mode elements running on top of Node.js and are not a part of a React Native app.